# Locking in java - Optimistic vs Pessimistic

Tags: java, locking

I was just trying to understand optimistic and pessimistic locking mechanisms and came across the definition of them at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)](http://Locking%20-%20Wiki)

If I try to relate the concepts to java instead of a database, am I right in saying that a synchronized usage is always pessimistic and a CAS (`AtomicInteger` and other classes) usage is always optimistic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I right in saying that a synchronized usage is always pessimistic
>   and a CAS (`AtomicInteger` and other classes) usage is always optimistic
>   ?

Yes you are correct.

Traditional locking mechanisms e.g. using synchronized keyword in java, is said to be **pessimistic** technique of locking or multi-threading.

The optimistic approach is like the old saying, “It is easier to obtain forgiveness than permission”, where “easier” here means “more efficient”. CAS is an example of **optimistic** technique. [StampedLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) also has support for optimistic locking.